# How to delete current task in pool threads?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I have this event handler in asp.net page:

```
protected void SetDescPoint(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new System.Threading.WaitCallback(foo));
    }
    catch (Exception)
    { }
}

private void foo(object a)
{
    try
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Start - " + DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss tt"));
        TimeSpan minutes = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(minutes);
        string path = UniquePath();
        File.Delete(path);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Deleted - " + DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss tt"));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("EXCEPTION - " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

SetDescPoint is event handler and fired in response to client event.As you can see the function foo has Thread.Sleep(10minutes) there is might be situation when event handler fired in time interval less than 10 minutes, so in that situation I need to delete current task(foo()) in pool threads.

Any Idea how can I implement it?

Comment: You can use [task cancellation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997396(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: You're holding a thread for nothing here. Instead of `Thread.Sleep`, use `Task.Delay` which uses a timer internally. And it has the nice side-effect of solving your problem by supporting the use of a CancellationToken to cancel the wait

Comment: @MartinLiversage, can you please show example how do I use task cancellation in my example?

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite your code to use `Task.Delay`. This has two benefits: you're not holding up a thread anymore (as `Task.Delay` uses a timer internally), and you can use a cancellation token to cancel the wait:

```
protected CancellationTokenSource CancellationToken { get; private set; }

protected void SetDescPoint(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

        this.CancellationToken = new CancellationTokenSource();

        Task.Run(() => foo(this.CancellationToken.Token), this.CancellationToken.Token);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    { }
}

private async Task foo(CancellationToken token)
{
    try
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Start - " + DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss tt"));
        TimeSpan minutes = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
        await Task.Delay(minutes, token);
        string path = UniquePath();
        File.Delete(path);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Deleted - " + DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss tt"));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("EXCEPTION - " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Whenever you want to cancel your task, just call `CancellationToken.Cancel()`

Answer (score 1):

A rather simplified way of dealing with this would be to keep track of a `CancellationTokenSource` for each path your create (I'm not sure if there a multiple paths or a simple path, but just in case), and then look it up once the event fires again.

Using this with `Task.Delay`, which asynchronously yields control in a non-blocking fashion, can achieve what you want:

```
private ConcurrentDictionary<string, CancellationTokenSource> pathsToTokens = 
                    new ConcurrentDictionary<string, CancellationTokenSource>();

protected async void SetDescPointAsync(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CancellationTokenSource existingTokenSource;
    var path = UniquePath();
    if (pathsToTokens.TryGetValue(path, out existingTokenSource))
    {
        existingTokenSource.Cancel();
    }

    var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    pathsToTokens.AddOrUpdate(path, cancellationTokenSource, 
                             (pathToFile, token) => cancellationTokenSource);

    try
    {
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10), cancellationTokenSource.Token)
                  .ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
    catch (TaskCanceledException tce)
    {
        // Token was cancelled, do something?
    }

    Foo(path);
    pathsToTokens.TryRemove(path, out cancellationTokenSource);
}

private void Foo(string path)
{
    try
    {
        File.Delete(path);
        Debug.WriteLine("Deleted - " + DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss tt"));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("EXCEPTION - " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

What happens with this code is that for each path you create, you allocate a new `CancellationTokenSource`. Every time the event is triggered, you check for an existing token. If it is in place, that means the event still hasn't finished, and you want to cancel it. Then, you asynchronously wait the amount of time you need. Note that `Task.Delay` is wrapped in a `try-catch` as calling `CancellationTokenSource.Cancel` will cause it to throw an exception once completed.

Comment: But  SetDescPointAsync function is code behind in ASP.NET page.When SetDescPointAsync function fired it rebuild all the page include pathsToTokens  variable

Comment: @Michael Well, you should of mentioned that in your question :)